# unable to access get data from http connection in blackbery

Tags: java, http, blackberry, connection

i have written something like this:

```
package mypackage;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import javax.microedition.io.StreamConnection;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Dialog;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.RichTextField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

/**
 * A class extending the MainScreen class, which provides default standard
 * behavior for BlackBerry GUI applications.
 */
public final class MyScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{
    private static String HEADER_CONTENTTYPE = "content-type";
    private static String CONTENTTYPE_TEXTHTML = "text/html";
    String content = "";
    private static final int STATE_0 = 0;
    private static final int STATE_1 = 1;
    private static final int STATE_2 = 2;
    private static final int STATE_3 = 3;
    private static final int STATE_4 = 4;
    private static final int STATE_5 = 5;
    private static final char HTML_TAG_OPEN = '<';
    private static final char HTML_TAG_CLOSE = '>';
    private static final char CR = 0x000D;
    private static final char LF = 0x000A;
    private static final char TAB = 0x0009;
    /**
     * Creates a new MyScreen object
     */
    public MyScreen()
    {
        // Set the displayed title of the screen
        setTitle("MyTitle");

        final ButtonField bf = new ButtonField("New");
        FieldChangeListener listener = new FieldChangeListener()
        {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) //respond
to button events
            {
                if(context != PROGRAMMATIC)
                {
                    if(field==bf)
                    {
                     //System.out.println("==============================");
                        fun1();
                    }
                }
            }   
        };
        RichTextField rtf = new RichTextField("hello");
        bf.setChangeListener(listener);
        add(bf);
    }

    void fun1()
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("asd");
            //Dialog.alert("asd");
            String str =
fun_dwn_txt("www.google.co.in");
            Dialog.alert(str);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {           Dialog.alert("Sorry");
            System.out.println("asd");

        }
    }

    String fun_dwn_txt(String str_url) throws Exception
    {
        StreamConnection s = null;
        s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(str_url);
        HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection)s;

        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        if (status == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            // Is this html?
            String contentType = httpConn.getHeaderField(HEADER_CONTENTTYPE);
            boolean htmlContent = (contentType != null &&
contentType.startsWith(CONTENTTYPE_TEXTHTML));

            InputStream input = s.openInputStream();

            byte[] data = new byte[256];
            int len = 0;
            int size = 0;
            StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();

            while ( -1 != (len = input.read(data)) )
            {
                // Exit condition for the thread. An IOException is
                // thrown because of the call to  httpConn.close(),
                // causing the thread to terminate.
//              if ( _stop )
//              {
//                  httpConn.close();
//                  s.close();
//                  input.close();
//              }
                raw.append(new String(data, 0, len));
                size += len;
            }

            raw.insert(0, "bytes received]\n");
            raw.insert(0, size);
            raw.insert(0, '[');
            content = raw.toString();

            if ( htmlContent )
            {
                content = prepareData(raw.toString());
            }
            input.close();
        }
        else
        {
            content = "No";
        }
        s.close();
        return content;
    }

    private String prepareData(String text)
    {
        final int text_length = text.length();
        StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer(text_length);
        int state = STATE_0;
        int count = 0;
        int writeIndex = -1;
        char c = (char)0;

        for ( int i = 0; i < text_length; ++i)
        {
            c = text.charAt(i);
            switch ( state )
            {
                case STATE_0:
                    if ( c == HTML_TAG_OPEN )
                    {
                        ++count;
                        state = STATE_1;
                    }
                    else if ( c == ' ' )
                    {
                        data.insert(++writeIndex, c);
                        state = STATE_5;
                    }
                    else if ( !specialChar(c) )
                    {
                        data.insert(++writeIndex, c);
                    }
                    break;

                case STATE_1:
                    if ( c == '!' && text.charAt(i + 1) == '-' &&
text.charAt(i + 2) == '-' )
                    {
                        System.out.println("Entering Comment state");
                        i += 2;
                        state = STATE_3;
                    }
                    else if ( Character.toLowerCase(c) == 'p' )
                    {
                        state = STATE_4;
                    }
                    else if ( c == HTML_TAG_CLOSE )
                    {
                        --count;
                        state = STATE_0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        state = STATE_2;
                    }
                    break;

                case STATE_2:
                    if ( c == HTML_TAG_OPEN )
                    {
                        ++count;
                    }
                    else if ( c == HTML_TAG_CLOSE )
                    {
                        if( --count == 0 )
                        {
                            state = STATE_0;
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case STATE_3:
                    if ( c == '-' && text.charAt(i+1) == '-' &&
text.charAt(i + 2) == HTML_TAG_CLOSE )
                    {
                        --count;
                        i += 2;
                        state = STATE_0;
                        System.out.println("Exiting comment state");
                    }
                    break;

                case STATE_4:
                    if ( c == HTML_TAG_CLOSE )
                    {
                        --count;
                        data.insert(++writeIndex, '\n');
                        state = STATE_0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        state = STATE_1;
                    }
                    break;

                case STATE_5:
                    if ( c == HTML_TAG_OPEN )
                    {
                        ++count;
                        state = STATE_1;
                    }
                    else if ( c != ' ' )
                    {
                        state = STATE_0;
                        if ( !specialChar(c) )
                        {
                            data.insert(++writeIndex, c);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        return data.toString().substring(0, writeIndex + 1);
    }

    private boolean specialChar(char c)
    {
        return c == LF || c == CR || c == TAB;
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

but on button click nothing is happening.. Even HttpConnection.HTTP_OK is not responding..

am i missing some detail which i have to mention in xml for internet connectivity...

Please suggest something...

Comment: yes, the `status` could possibly be something other than `HTTP_OK`. try printing it out

Comment: Unless I have missread your program logic you are calling reading an HTTP input stream on the event thread. This is not the way to do such things on the BlackBerry platform. You should not have any calls to blocking methods on the event thread.

Comment: actual the google is not the actual link, its 192.168.1.1/mobileapp/default.aspx virtual directory i have create in my computer...

Comment: use the article:http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Different_ways_to_make_an_HTTP_or_socket_connection.html?nodeid=826935&vernum=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- www.google.co.in is not a URL. You need to use http://www.google.co.in or https://www.google.co.in
- You are not specifying the connection method (BES, BIS-B, WiFi etc.). While this might work, it does not work always. Are you using WLAN? Then use `;interface=wifi` suffix in your connection string. BES? Use `;deviceside=false` and so on.

For more details, please see [this article](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Connecting-your-BlackBerry-http-and-socket-connections-to-the/td-p/206242). Using Connector API is not easy in BlackBerry. If you have a more recent BlackBerry (Device Software version 5.0+) then it might be easier to use the [Network API](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21128/Network_API_Overview_1251781_11.jsp)

Comment: There are other problems in the code as well, but these two are directly related to connections.